# somthing is causeing bottom scroll bar on home page in opera

Tags: html, css, opera

On my home page something is causing a bottom scroll bar too appear in opera any ideas ?

i have looked at all the elements and none seem to be over extending out. and this seems to only happen in opera and on phones.
i have tried

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and it removed the bar but i fear on smaller resolutions you wont be able to scroll if you need too ?
http://tshirthideout.com

Comment: Please post your code instead of just a link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: sorry i would post code but i have no clue where to start.

Comment: I took another look in firefly and the over over stepping I see is from the body tag its self ??? why is this only happening on my home page I don't get it.

Comment: There seem to be a few validation errors on your page, especially with regard to opening/closing elements etc. So Opera might be interpreting your invalid code differently. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftshirthideout.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: i have fixed all but 3 errors so far still the same ill see if the last few errors are causing this.

Comment: i fixed all the errors but one and it seems to be for google plus that appears on all pages. And this only happens on the home page so it must be something else causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the css below acting on `<div class="entry-content"></div>` in your *Latest Designs* `article` grid:

```
.entry-content { 
    width: 700px;
}
```

Any of the solutions below should do the trick:

- You could remove the unused `.entry-content div`s
- You could remove the above css rule or set a width appropriate for its parent container
- You could set `#content{overflow:hidden}`